# Files not renaming with rename command

Tags: shell, unix, rename

I have 3 files in my current working directory as follows:

```
abc def xyz.tgz
ghi jkl xyz.tgz
def klm zxc.tgz
```

I wish to rename the files such that the spaces should be replaced with an underscore. To achieve this I used the  following approach:

```
rename -v 's/\ /_/g' *tgz
```

Following are the issues:

1. The command executes without any error, but no files are renamed.
2. When the directory contains only one tgz file, an error is observed as follows:

   ```
   rename: not enough arguments
   ```
3. If I use the following:

   ```
   rename " " "_" *.tgz
   ```

   Only one occurrence of space is replaced with an underscore.

Comment: Is your `rename` the perl `rename` or util-linux `rename` or something else? It looks like it is the util-linux `rename` (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), which doesn't support `s/.../.../`.

Comment: `ls -l $(which rename)`

Comment: There is no bash `rename` command. This is an external command, not part of the shell, and shouldn't be tagged "bash".

Comment: why not use mv command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your system seems to provide the other [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename), which doesn't support Perl's substitution. You can still use it:

```
while ls *' '*tgz &> /dev/null ; do
    rename ' ' _  *' '*tgz || break
done
```

Or just use `mv` with parameter expansion:

```
for file in *' '*tgz ; do
    mv "$file" "${file// /_}"
done
```

Comment: Hmm. The first formulation loop strikes me as a bit dangerous. What if `rename` fails and exits with a nonzero status without renaming any files? Should put a `|| break` on it, at least, to prevent an infinite loop in the error case.

Answer (score 0):

This code will find all files or directories in the current directory and replace all spaces in their filenames with underscores:

```bash
find . -name '* *' -exec bash -c 'mv -v "$0" "`echo $0 | tr " " "_"`"' {} \;
```